# @Qualifier not working with multiple DataSource beans in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multiple-databases

I'm trying here to setup four MySQL data sources with spring boot application using four JPA entitymanagers. I'm new to spring and spring boot. I googled this to get a clue, but the results were very confusing, there are tons of approaches of configurations(but not for handling multi data sources), I'm not sure what to follow. Eventually I'm trying to setup four separate entity managers for each MySQL data sources and use them separately in transactions.

**application.properties**

```
# Database Properties
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.urlHotelPos: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelwebpos
db.urlHotelFinance: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelfinance
db.urlHotelInventory: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelinventory
db.urlReservation: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation
db.username: user
db.password: passwd

# Hibernate Properties
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.test.poswebservice.model.*
```

**DBconfigs.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBconfigs {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceHotelPos() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.urlHotelPos"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceHotelFinance() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.urlHotelFinance"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceHotelInventory() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.urlHotelInventory"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceReservation() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.urlReservation"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataSourceHotelPos")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryHotelPos() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceHotelPos());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataSourceHotelFinance")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryHotelFinance() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceHotelFinance());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataSourceHotelInventory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryHotelInventory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceHotelInventory());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("dataSourceReservation")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryReservation() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceReservation());

        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryHotelPos")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerHotelPos() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryHotelPos().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryHotelFinance")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerHotelFinance() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryHotelFinance().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryHotelInventory")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerHotelInventory() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryHotelInventory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryReservation")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerReservation() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryReservation().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
}
```

**Output >>**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Method entityManagerFactoryHotelPos in com.test.poswebservice.configs.DBconfigs required a single bean, but 4 were found:
    - dataSourceHotelPos: defined by method 'dataSourceHotelPos' in class path resource [com/test/poswebservice/configs/DBconfigs.class]
    - dataSourceHotelFinance: defined by method 'dataSourceHotelFinance' in class path resource [com/test/poswebservice/configs/DBconfigs.class]
    - dataSourceHotelInventory: defined by method 'dataSourceHotelInventory' in class path resource [com/test/poswebservice/configs/DBconfigs.class]
    - dataSourceReservation: defined by method 'dataSourceReservation' in class path resource [com/test/poswebservice/configs/DBconfigs.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

The @Qualifier annotation should avoid this issue, but here it's not working somehow. What's I'm doing wrong here? Please someone help me out, this is almost killing me :-( Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup it works this way that:

1. Remove the `@Qualifier` from your EMF beans
2. Add on every EMF Bean: `@DependsOn({"dataSource"})` with the correct `DataSource`
3. Indeed make one of the `DataSource`s `@Primary`

Comment: why should we make one of the data source beans `@Primary` here?(P.S. even in my previous setting the errors got away when making a data source bean `@primary`, I guess it's using the same primary data source for every EMF bean, I'll confirm that checking again.) making `@primary` means single EMF bean will accept multiple data source beans, right? one as primary and others as optionally? But in my case I just want the EMF bean to use one particular data source bean. am I figuring out anything wrong? thanks in advance for the clue.

Comment: I can confirm that this setup ain't work as it supposed to. EMF bean always pick the `@Primary` data source. No effect at all by the `@DependsOn`. `@Primary` is the dictator.

Answer (score 0):

should write code like this:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSourceHotelPos")
public DataSource dataSourceHotelPos() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is going to solve your problem (and my reputation does not allow me to comment that) but, you should not call EMF methods inside your bean definitions, because spring will already initiate a bean for that. Calling the method will create a second bean with exact same settings.

Instead you can try something like this:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryHotelPos")
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerHotelPos(@Qualifier("dataSourceHotelPos") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryHotelPos) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryHotelPos.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Since spring will try to initiate this bean, it sould autowire constructor parameters.
Hope it helps.